# Telegram Menu Keyboard bot

Tags: button, keyboard, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

Hello i have a question about bots in telegram, 2 years ago we could create telegram bots easily with chatfual bot, now i need make a bot that has menu button from bottom and when user tap on the button it answers the user and send the message like before, is there any full tutorial about it from youtube? i searched but i didn't get answer because all of the videos talks about inlinekeyboard but i need menu keyboard buttons not inlinekeyboard, i need full tutorial of python or any other language that tells me how can i make buttons like this, or is there any website that help me make bots like i said without coding? i don't want make these type of bots from other bots of telegram i want coding way or websites.
thanks.

like this [picture](https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-9CZQB9bbxfs/WRCPyAA4CPI/AAAAAAAAAWs/d7YbFEhNaaswHRYMfrdS0Nxt3ialNOPYQCLcB/s1600/Screen%2BShot%2B2017-05-08%2Bat%2B01.43.55.png) 
also want make more buttons whithin button

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, can you provide us some an exemple of what you want ?

Comment: @JonathanDelean ![like this](https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-9CZQB9bbxfs/WRCPyAA4CPI/AAAAAAAAAWs/d7YbFEhNaaswHRYMfrdS0Nxt3ialNOPYQCLcB/s1600/Screen%2BShot%2B2017-05-08%2Bat%2B01.43.55.png)

Answer (score 1):

Check that, it's tottaly what you search :

https://irazasyed.github.io/telegram-bot-sdk/usage/keyboards/#keyboards

And

https://medium.com/@chutzpah/telegram-inline-keyboards-using-google-app-script-f0a0550fde26

Comment: thank you so much sir that will help me :), i also found this that will help me too. This one https://dev.to/tbhaxor/making-telegram-bots-with-python-hid

Comment: i also have another question about resize buttons because they appear with big size. thanks