# Telegram bot: how do I make an in-line button to send messages

Tags: python, bots

I need a telegram bot that sends you inline button with some information bellow and when you press that button, it sends information (not an URL or something) I need a message with an image for example, when I search for tutorials it only shows me to put URLs, if someone can help me I would be so gratefull

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code-writing or tutorial service. Please [edit] your question and post [what you have tried so far](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592), including example input, expected output, the actual output (if any), and the [*full text* of any errors or tracebacks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146), *all as formatted text in the question itself.* Do not post images of text. The code should be a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

A quick search reveals that you are searching for a [keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62443957/telegram-menu-keyboard-bot) and if you look into the python-telegram-bot library, you can find examples like [inlinekeyboard2.py](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/v20.0a4/examples.inlinekeyboard2.html?highlight=Keyboard#inlinekeyboard2-py). Once you understand how it works, you can move on to sending a message. I suggest you take a look at the [resources](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/v20.0a4/index.html#resources) section in the same library, since you tagged python.

*If you try this and fail at a clear definable problem, then you might ask a question here (in a new thread), so that you can get an exact solution.*